# element.css('left') returns 'auto' even though it isn't on iPhone Safari only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile-safari

I have an element whose `left` CSS property I am trying to obtain and then set in Javascript. The element *has* the `left` property defined in an inline style. I see it when I inspect the element (through Safari on my Mac, acting as console for Safari on my phone).

However, the following functions:

```
console.log(getComputedStyle(reporting_table.find('thead.tableFloatingHeaderOriginal')[0]).getPropertyValue('left'));

console.log(reporting_table.find('thead.tableFloatingHeaderOriginal').css('left'));
```

...*both* return the string 'auto' instead of the inline style. I have tried the same code in Chrome and it works fine. Why is is Javascript not returning the correct value in mobile Safari?

[image: The inline style.]

*The inline style.*

[image: the console log of the element, and its left property]

*the console log of the element, and its associated `left` property*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it will work in your case, but you can try by just selecting the style attribute and the css property.Also note, the index need to be passed.
In your case you can do `$(".tableFloatingHeaderOriginal")[0].style.left`

```js
var x = $(".test")[0].style.color;
console.log(x)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" style="color:red;border:1px solid blue;width:100px;display:inline-block"> Hello</div>
```

Comment: This did work for me in the end! I'll accept the answer since it worked, however it would be great if this answer wound up with an explanation as to _why_ .css('left') failed Safari mobile.